# How do I subgroup this hash that has already been grouped?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a set of word strings which I am turning into a hash, grouped by the size of the string. I am doing this by:

```
hash = set.group_by(&:size)
```

resulting in

```
hash = {5=>[apple, andys, throw, balls], 7=>[bananas, oranges]}
```

I want to further group the hash values by first letter, so the the end results looks like:

```
hash = {5=>{a=>[apple, andys],b=>[balls],t=>[throw]}, 7=>{b=>[bananas], o=>[oranges]}}
```

I tried putting

```
hash.each_value do | value |
  value = value.group_by(&:chr)
end
```

after the first `group_by` but that only seems to return the original hash. I am admittedly a ruby beginner so I'm not sure if I could do this in one fell swoop, or exactly how `(&:size)` notation works, if I were asked to write it out. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update your hash you need to do like this

```
hash.each do |key, value|
  hash[key] = value.group_by(&:chr)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep the whole computation functional:

```
>> Hash[set.group_by(&:size).map { |k, vs| [k, vs.group_by(&:chr)] }]
=> {5=>{"a"=>["apple", "andys"], "t"=>["throw"], "b"=>["balls"]}, 
    7=>{"b"=>["bananas"], "o"=>["oranges"]}}
```